# moment.js Daylight Time vs. Standard Time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

You can see in the `new Date()` statement below that the local timezone in my machine is `GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`. So why is `momenjs` converting to `GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)` instead of local offset? Note that the input hour is 17 (5PM) and the output is 18 (6PM). I'm in EST and my machine does not have set any daylight saving time.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using .tz() method to set timezone for toDate method manually?

Comment: that requires to include an additional file and use the city names such as `date.tz('America/New_York')` I prefer not to do that.